# How to run com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask twice with different parameters in build.gradle?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, xjc

My goal is to generate java classes from two xsd schemas and place them in defined packages, i.e classes from first.xsd goes to com.example.first package, and second.xsd to com.example.second.
Sounds trivial for now and I create following code:

```
task genJaxb {
    doLast() {
        project.ant {
            taskdef name: "xjc", classname: "com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask", classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath
            xjc(destdir: sourcesDir, schema: "src/main/resources/xsd/first.xsd", package: "com.example.first", binding: bindingxml, extension: true) {
                arg(line: "-XtoString")
                binding(dir: 'src/main/resources', includes: '*.xjb')
                produces(dir: sourcesDir, includes: "**/*.java")
            }

            xjc(destdir: sourcesDir, schema: "src/main/resources/xsd/second.xsd", package: "com.example.second", binding: bindingxml, extension: true) {
                arg(line: "-XtoString")
                binding(dir: 'src/main/resources', includes: '*.xjb')
                produces(dir: sourcesDir, includes: "**/*.java")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I get only first package created. When I run my task with `debug` option I see for the second run:

```
[ant:xjc] build id of XJC is 2.3.3
[ant:xjc] Checking timestamp of <PROJECT_DIR>\src\main\resources\xsd\second.xsd
Class java.lang.Math loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
[ant:xjc] Checking timestamp of <PROJECT_DIR>\src\main\resources\jaxb\binding.xml
[ant:xjc] Checking timestamp of <PROJECT_DIR>\build\generated-sources\jaxb\generated\first\SOME_CLASS.java
```

so it looks like XJCTask was called with second schema and first package, which sounds weird.

I tried `gradle clean`, invalidated caches of Intellij Idea, removed all gradle caches from my user directory.
I expect XJCTask to generate classes from second schema in second package.